# Does a parse.com geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground count as an API request

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

Does anyone know whether implementation of `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` counts as an API request on parse, i.e. will it count towards my 30 requests per second limit?  Seeing as finding the location of an iPhone through the `CLLocationManager` does not use any network requests, I would suppose that it doesn't.

Comment: No it doesn't, it's merely a wrapper around CLLocationManager..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim virtually anything that you do with Parse counts against your API request limit. Look at them for what they are as a business, they collect revenue off of API request/s. So obviously the more you do the better for them. If you take a look at their definition of what constitutes an API request you will see a very vague, yet explicit answer. [see here](https://parse.com/plans/faq) specifically the first question for reference.

> Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app using one of the Parse SDKs or REST API, it counts as an API request.

So take a look at your code, your calling something in the background, so yes if you were fetching it from Parse you would **however** in this circumstance it is using the devices location as you mentioned in your question. 
**CLLocationManager** delegate delivers new coordinates and all geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground does is encapsulates that. 
Additionally, to answer your comment, queries do fall under this as well.

As a safe bet assume all your tasks are using an API request, this will create better coding habits and smarter structure outlines.

I believe the only thing that isn't used against you is cached information, which makes sense, since your originally already retrieved the information with an initial query there is no need to use another API request to get the same data as cached.

Sidenote: this even applies to the new local data store, even though it's not technically online, it will update the backend that you made a local data store query/save.

---

**REFERENCE** : https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still not convinced as to whether the geoPointForCurrentLocation will count towards my requests. It doesn't actually update anything on parse.com and my iPhone doesn't seem to display the network activity indicator in the status bar when I implement this code. What I'll do is set a view controller up that sends a load of  geoPointForCurrentLocation requests and see if they show up in my parse analytics

Comment: @TimWhiting no it doesn't count since again, it's not making a network call to Parse as stated above in my answer. I just didn't want you to get lost in Miabs answer where they stated only save and saveinbackground count against you.

Comment: sorry I did not totally understand what your conclusion was to the initial question, hence the edit. I couldn'r find anything on the link to the parse docs that said whether it would make a network call either which is why I provided my answer. Yes Miabs answer was misleading, I've always known a query would class as a request.

Comment: Yes sorry on my end @TimWhiting I was just trying to convey that it's always best case scenario for you to _assume_ that it counts against you even if it doesn't. This leads to you handling your tasks in more organized methods, take a look at PFQueryTableViewController. All tasks are handled with one query for the table as opposed to you doing numerous different queries for the same outcome yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this by putting the following code into a view controller that has no other parse api requests

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
            PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
                PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
                    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
                        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
                            PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (g: PFGeoPoint!, e: NSError!) -> Void in
                                println(g)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Nothing has come through on the performance tab on the analytics page for this app, so I would suggest that this is a "free" API. I have sent them an email to confirm